# Is there any ways to reduce the GPU Memory Caffe use?

Tags: caffe

I like caffe, but the amount of gpu memory caffe use is larger than mxnet(i test in ResNet-50 with mxnet-memonger). Is there any ideas, directions or alternative custom caffe for me to reduce the amount of gpu memory caffe use. Ideas and directions are enough and i will try to implement it in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: The most straightforward method to reduce the memory Caffe uses is to reduce the batch size while enabling gradient accumulation to achieve the same effective batch size, which you can do using the batch_size and iter_size parameters of the solver. For example, let's say the current batch_size parameter is set to 128 and you wish to decrease the memory by half, then you would set in the solver's prototxt:

```
batch_size: 64
iter_size: 2
```

Long answer: what takes up most of the memory in Caffe are not the weights of the layers (these are mostly fixed cost), but the intermediate computations between the layers, which scale linearly with the batch size. This is why decreasing the batch size will decrease the memory usage. Of course, just decreasing the batch size will hurt performance because it increases the variance of the gradient estimation.

However, we can decrease the batch size of each forward-backward iteration without affecting the gradient estimation by using gradient accumulation. What this means is that for each forward-backward step we use a small batch size B, while we only update the weights once every N iterations and accumulate all the gradients since the last update. This will give us an effective batch size of NxB.

Lastly, you might wonder if using this method will hurt the runtime performance of training a network. While in theory it could hurt performance if the forward-backward step would have processed each element in the batch in parallel, in practice this is not how Caffe is implemented(*), and each element in the batch is processed sequentially for each layer, so the end result has little to no effect on runtime performance.

(*) As a side note, at the past I've added support for Caffe for exactly that, and you can actually gain a slight speed up (~1.5x) during training at the expense of doubling the memory.

Comment: what do you mean intermediate computations between the layers? Are they the data blobs holding the feature maps and the blobs_ in net.hpp? In fact, ResNet has batch norm layers which needs a large batch_size.

Comment: each element in the batch is processed sequentially for each layer, so the end result has little to no effect on runtime performance. Is it slower than parallel processing in element dimension?

Comment: Indeed I mean the data blobs holding the feature maps. Regarding the effect on batch norm layers, you are right that it does make some difference in this case, however, I'm not sure to what extent it matters in practice. The reason I say it shouldn't matter much is that gradient accumulation was first suggested for implementing GoogLenet on Caffe which also uses batch norm.

Comment: If you are referring to Caffe's support for spreading the batch over several GPUs, then it has similar memory saving effects as gradient accumulation, that is each GPU is using a smaller batch size which is then combined. What I was referring to in the answer was parallel computation of elements on a *single* GPU.

Comment: I was referring to this article:  "A GPU Implementation of GoogLeNet" by Zhirong Wu, et al. which for some reason I can only find here now: http://textlab.io/doc/77271/a-gpu-implementation-of-googlenet

Comment: Great thanks! Is it possible to release or share some data blobs to reduce gpu memory. If it is possible, i want to try it. Any advises for me?

Comment: The only "trick" I know of is doing in-place computations for activation layers, which Caffe already does. I'm not sure how much more you can do, as this computations are needed for efficiently computing the gradients in the backward phase. While during training there's little you can do (to the best of my knowledge), during test time you can probably cut the memory usage by a large margin because you don't need all the intermediate computations.

Comment: Is it possible for caffe to store only some partial important data blob and retain the computing chain of each blob which can be used in recomputing these blob when needed?

Comment: The point of saving these intermediate results is to reduce the number of computations required for the gradient computations. Otherwise, you'll have to recompute the same values again and again, which for a feed-forward network would increase the complexity from O(n) iterations to O(n^2) where n is the number of layers.

Comment: For example, in alexnet if i want to compute all the gradient of weights between the recorded blob fc6 and the last layer loss. I can compute all the data blobs between the recorded blob fc6 and loss in one time and store them temporarily after compute the weights gradient, i release all the intermediate data blobs.

Answer (score 2):

[facebook-caffe](https://github.com/facebook/fb-caffe-exts) seems like what you want?

which optimizes memory usage by automatically reusing the intermediate activations when this is safe. This reduces the amount of memory required for intermediate activations by around 50% for AlexNet-style models, and around 75% for GoogLeNet-style models.

Oh, by the way I haven't tried it before.